# I need an advice about interval setting in small pinging app

Tags: user-interaction, winforms

I'm creating an application which let me to ping IP or IP range using time interval between each ping. My concern here is that if the interval will be allowed to be too small then my program would appear to do a ping flood.

What should I allow the minimum interval in milliseconds to be in my small app?

Comment: That's really difficult to give a generic answer to. What is the objective of the user? To have a constant real-time indication of availability (in that case ~250ms seems appropriate) or should he just be notified within "reasonable time" (in which case the minimum interval may may several minutes?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that pinging a publicly available IP address more that once per second would look highly suspicious.

In general you should not ping any more frequently than is useful, it will only lead to needless network traffic and congestion. For example if the purpose of your app were to notify a user visually of a network issue, pinging more frequently that a user can respond serves no purpose.

Perhaps a better solution would be to use a statistical based algorithm that takes into account packet loss, response times and network loading. The algorithm could be adaptive in that it would trade off network loading against the value of the information being collected.